# Regex to catch the last subpattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to build a regex that will replace the tokens %aa% and %cc% inside a string. All the cases are listed below:

```
1) /%aa%/%cc%/bb   => should replace only %cc%
2) /%aa%/%cc%/ac   => should replace only %cc%
3) /bb/%aa%/%cc%   => should replace only the last %cc%
4) /bb/%aa%        => should replace %aa%
5) /bb/ac/%aa%/%cc%/ac/bb => should replace only the last %cc%
```

I have the following regex which covers most of the case expect 2 and 5, basically those that contain the same chars as the tokens.

Regex pattern:  `%(?|(?|aa)|(?|cc))%(?=[^(aa|cc)]*($)+)`

Language is PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Like [`%(?:aa|cc)%(?!.*%(?:aa|cc)%)`](https://regex101.com/r/jD6qG6/1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex contains redundant branch reset groups (`(?|...|...)`) and the corrupt grouping that is placed into  a character class `[^(aa|cc)]*`, and an end of string anchor quantified (`($)+`), which is also a user error (no need to capture the anchor here and it is enough to test it once).

You can use the following regex:

```
'~%(?:aa|cc)%(?!.*%(?:aa|cc)%)~'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD6qG6/1)

For standalone strings, you can also add the `~s` singleline (DOTALL) modifier: `'~%(?:aa|cc)%(?!.*%(?:aa|cc)%)~s'`.

The `(?!.*%(?:aa|cc)%)` negative lookahead fails a match if either `aa` or `cc` appear after the `aa` or `cc` found so far.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Wiktor Stribiżew. That's exactly what I needed. I was struggling for the last 2 days with this by reading all the regex tutors I could find. Thanks for including an explanation as well. :)

Comment: One more hint: I am using non-capturing groups here, `(?:...)`, they are only meant to group, not capture subtexts. That is handy since the match data are not overfilled with unnecessary submatches.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please always provide your working solution downvote reasoning. There is no point in downvoting without leaving a comment - you have -1 forever, and no one wins.